# Any drivers for USB audio mic with db boost?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, audio

I have a decent little desktop mic, but it's a bit quiet in windows 7.

It uses the generic USB Audio driver.  The generic driver doesn't have any enhancements or boost features.

Are their any third party microphone drivers out there that have some enhancement features?

Answer (score 0):

I would look more at recording software features.  You'll have a lot more luck with amplifying the audio in something like [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/windows) than using a custom driver.  I can do this easily from the CLI on the linux side, so easily automated, but on the windows side?  I just don't know.

Comment: Some of the apps like skype seem to do okay with the levels. But ventrillo specifically needs more boost from the mic and doesn't have any in app settings.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I thought you meant for recording.  Skype has built-in noise reduction and some volume normalization.  You might be able to use something like virtual-audio-cable to pipe it into some amplification bit and have ventrilo use that device, but I don't think it exists off the shelf.